# How to create a tag (like class) inside a option inside a SELECT element?

Tags: html, select

I have a select box where I could have 2 kinds of options: cars or boats.
So I was think to create some like that:

```
<select>
  <option value="1" class="cars">Car1</option>
  <option value="2" class="boats">Boat1</option>
  <option value="3" class="cars">Car5</option>
  <option value="4" class="cars">Car7</option>
  <option value="5" class="boats">Boat4</option>
</select>
```

The aim is to identify what class of element was selected using jquery. Once class is an attribute not supported inside ["option"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)  what could be the best approach to tag these 2 different classes in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [accurate documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1). The `class` attribute appears on *HTML elements* (all of them).

Use a class. It's the standard way to mark an element as part of an arbitrary group.

---

And much as I dislike W3Schools, it doesn't get this particular issue wrong. The `class` attribute is mentioned on the other side of the link to *Global Attributes*.

Comment: Hi Quentin, as you can see, the w3Org says the same thing. No class to option. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element (Global attributes)

Comment: @zwitterion — That isn't what it says. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAMCd9wNPDpJh48umc5UclX66w-qNL-0eJI

Comment: … which takes you to here: https://www.evernote.com/l/AAOqni0diilH-p97FyfhIxVsszftbjAlQOg

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake. I did a wrong interpretation. w3.org says that 'option' support all global attributes too. Even w3School said the same "The 'option' tag also supports the Global Attributes in HTML.". Thanks